# Create an airtable OAuth token in python

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, oauth, airtable

I have code from Google that successfully uses the `google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file` API to open a browser and create a Google API Oauth2 token which is stored in a file and used in API calls:

```
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
def get_credentials():
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists(TOKEN_FILENAME):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(TOKEN_FILENAME, SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file( CREDENTIALS_FILENAME, SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open(TOKEN_FILENAME, 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())
    return creds
```

The `CREDENTIALS_FILENAME` is a JSON file that is downloaded from the Google OAuth console.

Airtable supports OAuth but it does not download an easy-to-use credentials file. But I am still able to get all of the key parameters. I put these into a JSON file and tried Google's code, but it didn't work.

Here are the key paramters I tried:

```
{"installed":
            {"client_id":"****",
             "auth_uri":"https://airtable.com/oauth2/v1/authorize",
             "token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
             "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
             "client_secret":"*****",
             "redirect_uris":["http://localhost"]}}
```

Airtable gives me this error:
[image]

Well, my client ID is correct. The `http://localhost` is what Google uses. The Google `InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file` runs a local webserver on a random port to get the response from the redirected web browser. Unfortunately, `from_client_secrets_file` doesn't allow me to specify a port.

I've tried other OAuth2 libraries with Airtable but can't get any of them to work either. I have lots of code. Most of it requires that I copy a URL from the console, paste it into my browser, then take the redirect URL (which produces an error) and paste it into the console.

This code gets quite far:

```
from oauthlib.oauth2 import WebApplicationClient
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
import secrets
import base64
import hashlib

def generate_pkce_pair():
    """ Generate a code_verifier and code_challenge for PKCE. """
    code_verifier = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(secrets.token_bytes(32)).rstrip(b"=").decode('utf-8')
    code_challenge = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(hashlib.sha256(code_verifier.encode('utf-8')).digest()).rstrip(b"=").decode('utf-8')
    return code_verifier, code_challenge

def main():
    client_id = '****'
    redirect_uri = 'https://localhost:8080/'  
    scope = ['schema.bases:read']

    # Generate PKCE code verifier and challenge
    code_verifier, code_challenge = generate_pkce_pair()

    # OAuth2 client
    client = WebApplicationClient(client_id)
    oauth = OAuth2Session(client=client, redirect_uri=redirect_uri, scope=scope)

    # Authorization URL
    authorization_url, state = oauth.authorization_url(
        url='https://airtable.com/oauth2/v1/authorize',
        code_challenge_method="S256",
        code_challenge=code_challenge
    )

    print("Please go to this URL and authorize:", authorization_url)

    # Get the authorization code from the callback URL
    redirect_response = input('Paste the full redirect URL here: ')

    # Fetch the access token
    token_url = "https://api.airtable.com/oauth/token"
    token = oauth.fetch_token(
        token_url=token_url,
        authorization_response=redirect_response,
        client_secret=None,
        code_verifier=code_verifier)

    print("Access token:", token)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Giving me this:

[image]

Redirecting to a `localhost:8080` URL which can't be read. That's okay, I paste in the redirect URL directly into the console, but then get this error:

```
oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.CustomOAuth2Error: ({'type': 'INVALID_API_VERSION'})
```

And I can't figure out how to specify the API version.

So I need to either:

1 - Specify a valid redirect_uri to airtable that works with the Google library, or
2 - Specify the API version for the `OAuth2Session` call.

Answer (score 0):

> So I need to either:
>
> 1 - Specify a valid redirect_uri to airtable that works with the Google library, or 2 - Specify the API version for the OAuth2Session call.

To answer question 2, [according to the documentation](https://airtable.com/developers/web/api/oauth-reference#token-expiry-refresh-tokens)

> Access tokens expire after 60 minutes. You will need to use the refresh_token returned from your requests to `/oauth2/v1/token` (both from new authorizations and when refreshing a token, explained below) to request a new access token after it is expired.
>
> This is done by making a new POST request to `/oauth2/v1/token` with the following headers and request body.

So, change your

```
token_url = "https://api.airtable.com/oauth/token"
```

to

```
token_url = "https://api.airtable.com/oauth2/v1/token"
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work. It produces the same results. In my first version I get `oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.CustomOAuth2Error: ({'type': 'INVALID_API_VERSION'})`. In my second version I get, in the window, `This third-party app failed to properly construct a request to Airtable: invalid client_id or mismatched redirect_uri`

Comment: @vy32 weren't you getting in the second version `oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.CustomOAuth2Error: ({'type': 'INVALID_API_VERSION'})` ?

Comment: As you might imagine, I have a lot of versions. So I just took the code above and pasted it into a file, fixed the CLIENT_ID, and ran it. It printed the URL that took me to Airtable. Airtable then redirected the browser to a localhost: address, which failed, I took that address and pasted it in, and got the same error: `oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.CustomOAuth2Error: ({'type': 'INVALID_API_VERSION'})`

Comment: So it didn't fix the `INVALID_API_VERSION` error that you were getting in code with OAuth2Session?

Comment: No, it did not.

Answer (score 0):

API_URL = 'https://api.airtable.com/v%s/'
API_VERSION = '0'

checkout this version type base id , and api key

[https://api.airtable.com/v0/[BASE_ID]/[TABLE_NAME]](https://api.airtable.com/v0/%5BBASE_ID%5D/%5BTABLE_NAME%5D)

Comment: Hi. I'm not quite sure what to do. Are you saying I should use a different API URL in the OAuth request? My minimum working example (which is not working) doesn't have an API_URL variable in it.